# displaying a styled content in a JTextArea

Tags: java, performance, swing, styles, jtextarea

I was wondering if there is a way to style text in a JTextArea;

**i have to insert lines of text that each one contains segments that might have different styles and type of content; type of content would determine the actions available to the segment they are related to.**

- I examined JTextPane and JEditorPane and found them too complicated, slower and less adapted to my needs.
  the best solution I came up with was to extend the BasicTextUI and the PlainDocument classes.

could it be done another way? any advice to enhance the performance  ?
thank you.

Comment: Could you show us your code please? Also why do you need to consider the speed / performance of a `JTextArea`?

Comment: *"I was wondering if there is a way to style text in a JTextArea;"* A text area is for plain text only, so ..no. Use a `JEditorPane` or a `JTextPane` which both support styled text.

Comment: @hamena314 the code is too long to be posted here, speed and performance are required because the component will contain a lot of data, and the application using the component has many others...in an other word why don't ask for performance if you can have it ?

Comment: *"I examined JTextPane and JEditorPane and found them too complicated, slower and less adapted to my needs."* 1) Too complicated for you to understand? Do you understand how to write HTML? Use that. Note that 'styled text' is a complicated area, so expect a learning curve no matter how you style it. 2) 'slower' - A styled text document takes time to format. Having said that, it should support a few thousand lines without problem, and that is already far too much text to expect the end user to read. 3) 'adapted to needs' That raises a question - ***exactly*** what is the requirement? ..

Comment: .. 4) *"the code is too long to be posted here"* We don't want you dumping your project here (or even linking to it on GIT). Instead post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Use either an existing document on the net (hot link to it in code), or a loop to create the 'long data'.

Comment: In expansion of point 4 above re. 'existing document'. The Java 8 classes in the Java Docs contains 4240 classes - use URL http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html for that..

Comment: @AndrewThompson easy the frog !!  read well before jumping on people like that :D. my code works fine I was just asking if things could be done better; because; and you must already know that the default available components are for standard use.

Comment: *"read well before jumping on people like that"* That was a fairy alighting on your shoulder. If I'd 'jumped on you' you'd have trouble breathing. ;)

Comment: i didn't know you're an old school, so no offence, my apologies and total respect to you wise man (but still, "read well before jumping on people like that" :P)

Answer (score 2):

> I examined JTextPane and JEditorPane and found them too complicated

Yes, well that is the way programming works. If you want to do something more complicated then you need to use a more advanced component.

A JTextArea doesn't support styled text which is why it is easy to use. A JTextPane does support styled text so it is a "little" more complicated.

A JTextPane really isn't all that complicated once you create a few styles to use for each group of text. For example:

```
JText textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText( "This is regular text"");
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

//  Add some styled text

SimpleAttributeSet green = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(green, Color.GREEN);

try
{
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nThis is green text.", green);
}
catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
```